# Jenkins Publish over CIFS - jobwise credential configuration

Tags: jenkins, credentials, smb, cifs

**Is it possible to configure my cifs credentials jobwise?**

The jenkins we are using is a shared jenkins and therefore I would like to configure the credentials in my job only.

As I unterstood from the general *Publish Over* documentation it should be possible.. [Publish Over Wiki](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over#PublishOver-Credentials)

But in the specific *Publish Over CIFS* this feature is not mentioned [Publish Over CIFS Wiki](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+CIFS+Plugin)

Am I just blind that I don't see these options in my jobconfiguration or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think this might not be possible at the current time.

I need to do a PR in the [repository](https://github.com/jenkinsci/publish-over-cifs-plugin) but did not have time for that, yet.